# f# Rprovider issues with TTR Package

Tags: r, f#

I don't know if anyone has had any issues with Rprovider and the TTR package. I am currently trying to use the RSI indicator from TTR however each time I call the function, I get the following error:

Additional information: Error in TTR::RSI(price = fsr_9396_17, n = 2) :

could not find function "try.xts"

My code that I am running is below:

```
let times=  [ "Input"=>timeser
              "RSI2"=>R.RSI(timeser,80).GetValue<Series<_, double>>()] |> frame
```

If I change RSI to rollmeans then the code works perfectly. If anyone has any experience with solving this problem would be great if they could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `RSI` function only works if the `xts` package is imported before the call. I'm not entirely sure if this is an R provider bug or some non-standard thing in the RSI function, but you can workaround it by explicitly calling `library(xts)` before:

```
// Add this to make the following code work
R.eval(R.parse(text="library(xts)"))

// Very basic call to RSI that now works
let timeser = series [ for s in 0.0 .. 100.0 -> DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(s) => s ]
R.try_xts(timeser)
R.RSI(timeser,80)
```

Comment: Could you just load the `TTR` package since it Depends on `xts`?

Comment: Yes, calling `library(TTR)` apparently works too. I think the R provider should be doing that behind the scenes (this usually works), but it does not seem to work in this case for some reason... I logged this here: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider/issues/121

Comment: I would be surprised if almost all TTR functions work if `library(TTR)` hasn't implicitly or explicitly been called, since TTR makes extensive use of xts internally.